# Grab the filename in Unix out of full path

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to get `"abc.txt"` out of `/this/is/could/be/any/path/abc.txt` using Unix command.
Note that `/this/is/could/be/any/path` is dynamic.

Any idea?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

In `bash`:

```
path=/this/is/could/be/any/path/abc.txt
```

If your path has spaces in it, wrap it in `"`

```
path="/this/is/could/be/any/path/a b c.txt"
```

Then to extract the path, use the [basename function](https://ss64.com/bash/basename.html)

```
file=$(basename "$path")
```

or

```
file=${path##*/}
```

Comment: `file=${path##*/}` will work in `ksh` as well; in fact, bash borrowed this feature from ksh. Any `sh` on any Linux system is likely to support this, too.

Comment: It should be enclosed in double quotes to avoid problems with funny characters in the file name: `file="$(basename $path)"` or `file="${path##*/}"`

Comment: You answer is good, but if the designer wants the script to work with paths that have space, the first answer needs quotation marks around the  $path, so: file=${basename "$path"} . I've made an edit of the answer to fix that but I think it needs your approval. @Keith Thompson, file="${basename $path}" wouldn't work, the quotes need to be on $path or the basename function won't work properly.

Comment: This is really useful, and basename can remove file extensions as well.

Answer (score 6):

`basename path` gives the file name at the end of path

Edit:

It is probably worth adding that a common pattern is to use back quotes around commands e.g. `basename ...`, so UNIX shells will execute the command and return its textual value.

So to assign the result of basename to a variable, use

```
x=`basename ...path...`
```

and $x will be the file name.

Comment: I've tried this and basename seems to be falling over on paths where there is a space in the name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `basename /this/is/could/be/any/path/abc.txt`

Comment: keep an eye on the times ... answered Apr 12 '12 at 13:15 vs Apr 12 '12 at 13:16

Answer (score 2):

You can use dirname command

```
$ dirname $path
```

Comment: That is the reverse what OP is asking for: `dirname any/path/abc.txt` -> `any/path`, while they were asking for `abc.txt`