# Getting last element of a path (different from #10124314 as basename falls over)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, filenames

I need to process a couple of thousand PDF files sorted alphabietically on their filename ideally from `bash`. So from my simple perspective I need to walk a tree of files, stripping off path as I go and then do various grepping, sorting etc

Having seen an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124314/grab-the-filename-in-unix-out-of-full-path) I've tried doing a

```
tim@MERLIN:~/Documents/Scanned$ basename `find ./ -print`
```

but that gets messed up by some directory names which have spaces in them - e.g. there is one called `General Letters` which acts like a chicken-bone in the works and results in

```
basename: extra operand ‘Letters’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

I can't see a way to get `find` to strip out the pathname and I would prefer to use `find` given its plethora of options to filter on age, size etc. Nor can I see any way to get `basename` to cope gracefully with spaces in this context.

I considered using `cut` but I can't work out how to get `cut` to give me the last field by doing something like `cut -d/ <whatever>` I'm sure there must be an easy way to do it: some sort of in-line `sed` or `awk` script?

I don't particularly want the buggeration of writing a perl/Python script to do it for me as I know I *should* be able to do it from the command line.

So any simple tips or suggestions?

## Updated/Solved

Many thanks to Cyrus the solution is

```
tim@MERLIN:~/Documents/Scanned$ find . -name *.pdf -printf '%f\n' | sort
```

Comment: Please update your question to provide a link to "answer #10124314". I think you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10124314/827263).

Comment: Proper direction recursion along with `pushd` and `popd` is what you probably need here. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
find ./ -printf '%f\n'
```

`%f`: File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I was after. `find . -name *.pdf -printf '%f\n' | sort` gets me pretty close to where I need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution using `awk`:

```
find ./ | awk -F'/' '{ print $NF }';
```

It simply uses `/` as delimiter and prints the last value of the line.

Or with `grep`:

```
find ./ | grep -oE "[^/]+$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Through `sed`,

```
find ./ | sed 's/.*\/\(.*\)$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get a list of `pathnames` (recursively) but want sort them  by `filenames` (not by path names) you can use:

```
find . -printf '%f|%p\n' | sort -k 1 -t'|' | cut -d'|' -f2-
```

You need a `GNU` find for this. (Linux ok, not default in OS X).

Without the GNU find, you can do the above with:

```
find . -print | sed 's:\(.*\)/\(.*\)$:\2\|\1/\2:' | sort -k 1 -t'|' | cut -d'|' -f2-
```

(Assuming there is no `\n` in the filenames)

Comment: In this instance the path name doesn't actually matter: I am looking for "holes" in the numbering scheme of the documents (as I suspect some have been deleted or stored somewhere bizarre or never saved). But thanks for the steer.