# how to find last selected character in shell script

Tags: shell

I have assigned following string to a variable.

```
line="/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common/location.txt"
```

If I want to access common location (/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common)
how can I split this in last "/" ?

Comment: To give you a good answer please be more accurate: Which OS and shell do you use?

Comment: Add this after your line: `echo $line | sed 's/.\{13\}$//'`. This command removes last 13 characters from the string.

Comment: @UsersUser - the operating system doesn't matter much.  The shell though...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grab the filename in Unix out of full path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124314/grab-the-filename-in-unix-out-of-full-path)

Answer (score 1):

In most unix-style operating systems, there's a program called `dirname` which does this for you:

```
$ line="/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common/location.txt"
$ dirname "$line"
/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common
```

The command is of course available from any shell, since it's not part of the shell per-se, though you might need to assign the variable differently.  For example, in csh/tcsh:

```
% setenv line "/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common/location.txt"
% dirname "$line"
/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common
```

If you want to strip off the file using shell commands alone, you'll need to specify what shell you're using, since commands vary.  For example, in /bin/sh or similar shells (like bash), you could use "Parameter expansion" (look it up in the man page, there's lots of good stuff):

```
$ line="/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common/location.txt"
$ echo "${line%/*}
/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use below command if your line variable contains same number of directories always

```
echo $line |  cut -d "/" -f1-5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line="/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common/location.txt"
path="${line%/*}"
file="${line##*/}"

## contents of the variables after extraction
#  path is '/remotepath/mypath/localpath/common'
#  file is 'location.txt'
```

It's called **parameter expansion/substring extraction** in bash.